# How to automate and not create a new project structure every time for javascript development

Tags: javascript, npm, vim, eslint, prettier

I wanted to avoid the hassle of creating a project structure for all my projects so I could use [ALE](https://github.com/dense-analysis/ale) linting and fixing. I took one approach (at the end) but I'm pretty sure there is a more elegant solution. Anyways, In general, the steps are:

> - create [package.json](https://github.com/dense-analysis/ale)
> - install all packages with npm
> - for [eslint](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/getting-started#configuration):
>
>   - create [.eslintrc.{json,js,yaml}](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/getting-started#configuration)
>   - install plugins and create rules
>   - integrate plugins ([airbnb](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript), [prettier](https://prettier.io/), etc)
>   - repeat this for each new project

For npm installs I know `-g` can install globally, but if I place the `.eslintrc.json` in my home folder, when I open it in VIM, it says it could not load the plugins (airbnb, prettier, etc) style guides. Presumably because there is no node_modules folder in my project folder.

So, I decided to create one template folder with all the stuff from the sequence above. and copied that structure to a folder where I'm opening my `.html`, `.css`, `.js` or `.json` files as an `autocmd` from VIM.

Here is the relevant part of my `.vimrc`

```
autocmd FileType javascript,json,css,html silent exec '! '.$HOME.'/Documents/eslint-template/prepare.sh
```

and here is the `prepare.sh`:

```
$ cat Documents/eslint-template/prepare.sh 
#!/bin/bash

echo Preparing environment...
templateFolder=$HOME/Documents/eslint-template
files=( $templateFolder/{.,}* )
for file in ${files[@]}; do
  [ "$(basename $0)" == "$(basename $file)" ] && continue
  destFile=$PWD/$(basename $file)
  diff -q $file $destFile > /dev/null 2>&1 ||
    cp -r $file $PWD/
done

rsync -azz --delete $templateFolder/node_modules/ node_modules/ > /dev/null 2>&1

echo Preparation completed!
```

I've been tweaking and testing and it has been working fine (I will run more tests, though). But it may take some 10 to 15 seconds to open a simple `.html` file as it has to copy the entire [node_modules](https://docs.npmjs.com/configuring-npm/folders.html#node-modules) structure from the template to the new project. Even the `-zz` option from [rsync](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync), when run from within VIM seems to be a lot slower than running from terminal directly.

So, the question is, what are the other alternatives to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use something similar to this [CLI tool](https://github.com/dkundel/create-project). You can put your project structure in the `templates` folder. Please avoid putting `node_modules` there because we can always install the dependencies listed in `package.json`.

Comment: But avoiding downloading a bunch of package every time is the very thing I want to avoid.

Comment: It's a bad practice to store the node_modules folder. For bigger projects, the size can go up to gigabytes. Plus, a node_modules folder from MacOS may not run well in other platforms.

Comment: But I will have the node_modules folder at the project level anyways, no? What you mean is that I would not need to store the modules twice (one for the project and another for the template), correct? But if I have 10 projects, I will store it 10 times instead of 10 + 1 (template), and that starts to lose meaning, no? To me it looks like the ideal way to save space would be by using a global node_modules, but I could not, as I posted. As for the platform, why would I try to use modules from one system to another? I asked inside the same machine.

Comment: The node_modules won't be the same for every project. You will need same packages in a project you don't need in another one. Also, sometimes you need to support an older version in one project and a newer one in another project. It will be hard to do this with only one global package.